# Suggest a good Ajax framework to be used with Spring/java?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Greetings all
i want to use ajax with spring framework
and i was wondering what framework is easy to use and has good support & samples with spring framework, like the DWR, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring team prefers Dojo.  I believe it's built into Spring.

There's also BlazeDS support if you want to use Flex.

Comment: "built in to Spring"?  How so?

Comment: Don't they use it extensively in Spring Web Flow?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Webflows internally uses Dojo components on the clienside for Ajax calls. You can also combine your own distribution of Dojo (Spring does not include all the GUI goodies in their Dojo distribution) so that whenever you do use Dojo, you don't end up with one version of Spring and one of your own.

Answer (score 1):

We have been successfully using JQuery and ExtJs frameworks on the client side and Spring MVC / annotations on the server side.
I heard a lot about mootools also.